# notifyDataSetChanged not working from within custom adapter

Tags: android, listview, custom-adapter, notifydatasetchanged

I'm faced with strange problem. I've made a ListView, populated it with adapter and everything works fine until I want to delete any item. After I press confirmation button view really deletes, but text inside of it doesn't changes on the text from next view.
For example I've got such items in ListView:

- Item 1
- Item 2
- Item 3

When I press delete Item 2, Item 3 disappears but text in view on position 2 doesn't changes. I know that Item 2 was deleted as I use database for storing data and after app restart everything show as expected. I suppose that problem is in reuse of views by View Holder but I can't figure out how to change text in second view.
Here is code that doesn't work (at least I think that problem is here)

```
confirmDeleteButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {//this button is in dialog
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        DBController.init(context).delete("main", "id=" + item.get(position).getId(), null);//deleting item from database
                        remove(getItem(position)); //removing view from adapter
                        notifyDataSetChanged(); //notifying adapter
                        dialog.dismiss(); //closing dialog
                    }
                });
```

### **SOLUTION**

Just use RecyclerView instead of ListView.

Comment: Can you show where and how you set the values?

Answer (score 0):

First you have to remove the data from adapter like `adapter.remove(adapter.getItem(position));`

and then call `notifyDataSetChanged()`

Comment: He setting the onClickListener in the adapter, so                         remove(getItem(position)); is the same thing as you are suggesting.

Answer (score 0):

don't use the get position to delete the datas, first setid() to confirm buttons like, `confirmDeleteButton.setid(position)` used in getview adapter class.

then remove the id based on `getid()` like:

```
DBController.init(context).delete("main", "id=" + item.get(v.getid()).getId(), null);//deleting item from database 
remove(v.getid()); //removing view from adapter
```

Comment: remove method requires type of Item not int but if I do something like this `remove (getItem(view.getId()));` nothing changes. The same as if I doing like this (item is an ArrayList<Item>) - `item.remove(position);` Looks like I should rewrite this part using RecyclerView.

Comment: have u setid for confirmDeleteButton in adapter, if u not set id means u will never get the correct datas.then use viewholder class in adapter

Comment: I did, but problem still remains. I think that is because of using viewholder pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Is better if you use:

```
adapter.notifyItemRangeRemoved(int positionStart, int itemCount)
adapter.notifyItemRemoved(int position)
```

More info: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html

Comment: In case of using RecyclerView - yes, but firstly I used ListView, so there were some problems.

Comment: In any moment where you doing position+1 or something similar that might be why you where getting next in array

Comment: I try not using position+1 (or any other math operation) as it could lead to unpredictable appearance of ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException. And in case of using of adapter it would lead to such exception sooner or later as it uses arrays as source of data. In my case problem was, as I understood, in reusing views by ViewHolder in ListView. So when I was deleting item in array and notifying adapter it used old view (with old item's name) to show me replaced view. Thanks for advice!